# Dart web UI and iterating inside a table

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I tried to iterate over data inside a table:

```html
  <table>
    <template iterate="entry in data">
      <tr>
        <template iterate="value in entry.values">
          <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </template>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
```

For some reason I'm getting this error message when I build:

> Unexpected end tag (template) in table context caused voodoo mode.

It works fine when I iterate inside `ul`:

```html
  <ul>
    <template iterate="entry in data">
      <template iterate="value in entry.values">
        <li>{{ value }}</li>
      </template>
    </template>
  </ul>
```

I imagined that using tables and iteration shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution, although I still do not know what the issue was:

```html
<table template iterate="entry in data">
  <tr template iterate="value in entry.values">
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/191 - quote: "Tables in HTML are very picky about their child node types, which is why we can't support <template> tags there. However what we can do is provide a better error."

Comment: I see. Fortunately we can use the `iterate` attribute right on the `table` and `tr`.

Comment: I had to find this solution also at one point, kai make an easy to use data grid :)

Comment: At one point, you could omit the template attribute. I believe it's now required.

Comment: @SethLadd yes I believe that's the eventual goal, but right now you still need it. I'd love to type `<div if="{{ foo}}">...</div>`. :)

Comment: This is incorrect right now. It should be: `<table><tbody template iterate="entry in data">etc...`